# Ratio of the two phases during phases transition (liquid-gas) : is it a general behavior of first order?

Tags: phase-transition

In the liquid-gas phase transition, we have a mixture between the two phases during the phase transition: a part of the volume is pure liquid and another part is pure gas, but the two are separated.

I would like to know if it is a general behavior of first order phase transitions or if it is only for gas-liquid behavior that this "separated mixtures" occurs ?

Comment: Given that they are different thermodynamic phases, how are they not separated? How would you envision a mixed liquid-gas (or solid-liquid) phases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general all first order phase transitions have this behavior. Since the state must `jump over a gap' so to say, the transition does not happen everywhere at the same time as in second order phase transitions. There needs to be a process of [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation), where the new phase starts to grow from points in the medium. If everything is perfectly smooth and symmetric so that these nucleations cannot take place, one gets the situation where a liquid can be [superheated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheating), without it turning into the gas phase.